# Eclipse Plugin-Development Debugger out of Sync

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

for some internal development I currently customize a Eclipse Plug in. The Plug in I use is deployed as .jar File. Now I extracted the Content and imported it as Eclipse Plug in project. Everything works fine until is start to add some Code.

For testing the new functionality I like to debug my code. Therefore I run the Eclipse Plug in project in Debug mode. I've got a Debugging connection but the line of code highlighted in the editor doesn't match with the code.

```
1 private void a(){
2   doSomething();
3 }
4 
5 private void b(){
6   doSomethingElse();
7 }
```

For example the Debug view says I am in the Method `b()`. But the Highlighter, in the Text-Editor, point to line 3.

I tried several things like Cleaning and searched nearly everywhere in the Debug-Configurations but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the displayed code doesn't fit what the debugger tells you it is executing, then you are simply not debugging the code that you see in the editor (but probably still the version without your modifications).

There are a lot of potential reasons for this. For the most easy failure please check your debug configuration. On the plugins page of the debug configuration there are plugins shown as living in your workspace and being provided by the Eclipse installation. Make sure that for your plugin the checkbox is at the workspace version, like the first checkbox in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The debugger highlights the code that is just about to be executed. When the debugger says you are in method `b()` it is simply telling you that it is about to debug method `b()`